# Exception occurs if you instantiate a EdgeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Exception occurs if you instantiate a EdgeDriver.

【Exception Information】

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: No such driver (NoSuchDriver)

【StackTrace】

> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>
> OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(String edgeDriverDirectory, EdgeOptions options)
>
> ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)

Environment is as follows.

- OS:Windows 10 Pro
- VS.NET:2015 Enterprise
- [Microsoft Edge Driver is installed.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48740)
- Selenium WebDriver API .NET:Ver 2.48.00

Exception occurs in the following code.

**IWebDriver webDriver = new EdgeDriver(serverPath, options);**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverPath = "Microsoft Web Driver";
            if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%"), serverPath);
            }
            else
            {
                serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%"), serverPath);
            }
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
            IWebDriver webDriver = new EdgeDriver(serverPath, options);     // Exception occured!!
            webDriver.Url = "https://www.google.co.jp";
            IWebElement element = webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            element.SendKeys("test");
            element.Submit();
        }
    }
}
```

What kind of problems do will be considered?

Comment: I get the same error using the same version of Microsoft WebDriver (build 10550). I did NOT get this error with the previous build 10240 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212. However not all the WebDriver command are implemented in build 10240.

Comment: Hi, Aron.Reply Thank you.As of comments we worked that it is old version!We'll try to contact Microsoft and Selenium team. Thank you very much.Also is sorry it will late reply.

Comment: When I run Visual Studio as Administrator, I get a different error:

'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
EdgeDriver exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:2295/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess based on experience is that you're running the incorrect version of **MicrosoftWebDriver.exe**.

The executable is built with Windows but ships separately and takes a hard dependency on being the same build as the OS it's running on.

You can find what build of the OS you're on by following these steps:

> 1. Go to **Start > Settings > System > About** and denote the OS Build.
>
>    The releases so far are:
>
>    - Windows 10 - TH1 - 10240
>    - Windows 10 Fall Update - TH2 - 10586
>    - Windows 10 Anniversary Update - RS1 - 14393
> 2. Next you'll want to visit Micorosoft's WebDriver page and choose the appropriate download:
>      https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: I followed those steps to get the correct version, but it keeps failing on the unknown error.